# Hibernate strict OneToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, strict

I have an Hibernate OneToOne relationship mapped via an association table. :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")   
public class Table1 {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="colTable1", nullable=false) 
    private String colTable1;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
        @JoinTable(name="associationtable", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idTable1"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idTable2") 
        ) 
    @NotNull
    private Table2 table2;

....
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table2")   
public class Table2 {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="colTable2", nullable=false)
    private String colTable2;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table2") 
        @NotNull
    private Table1 table1;

...

}
```

I would like to have a strict 1<>1 relations so i added @NotNull annotation.

BUT, when i try to save into database by doing this :

> Table1 table1 = new Table1(...);
>   Table2 table2 = new Table2(...);
>   table1.setTable2(table2);
>   table2.setTable1(table1);
>
> dao.save(table1);

the following exception is raised :

> org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient > value - transient instance must be saved before current operation.

I tried saving table2 first and other solutions but nothing worked.
I do not see how to solve this chicken-egg problem...

Of course i will always have a transient property when creating a new object of this OneToOne relationship, but I don't care checking at transient status ...

Why @NotNull annotation is checking this transient status ? Is there a way to tell him checking only nullability and not transient ?

If not, how can i do to have a strict OneToOne relationship via an association table ?

Thanks !

Comment: When you say "mapped via an association table", can you please copy and paste the exact code defining the relationships in Table1 and Table2? What annotations are you using in each object and which one defines the relationship?

Comment: I edited to be more precise.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that what you want to do is possible. If you consider the order of actions that Hibernate must perform in the database to make this work, both objects must first be persisted (to generate IDs) and THEN the relationship is written to the link table. It seems likely that both objects must exist in a persistent state without that relationship defined before the relationship can be established. This is an unusual way to define a one to one relationship, and when you say "strict" you should consider how this can be enforced at the SQL level.

Comment: This NotNull annotation should be called NotNullAndNotTransient :p . So what is the standard way to enforce a strict OneToOne relationship at Hibernate level ?

Comment: Normally one side would "own" the relationship more explicitly. So, on Table1 table2 would be annotated with JoinColumn instead of JoinTable. Again, though, you could only have NotNull on one side of that relationship. It comes down to how you could enforce the "strictness" of this relationship in SQL. One row always has to be inserted before the other exists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I tried with JoinColumn and a foreign key in the owning table (table1). I can enforced 1<>1 relationship by putting NotNull on both side. It raised an exception when one of the NotNull fields is missing, but never complained about a transient problem. In logs, by saving table2 or table1, Hibernate insert table2 first and then table1. I don't really understand why there is no transient problem with JoinColumn but there is this transient pb with JoinTable ?

Comment: Probably because this is the more usual way of implementing at 1 to 1 relationship the Hibernate developers have considered this use case when saving a NotNull relationship, but not accounted for using a JoinTable for the same thing.